# Transformer open circuit test

Tags: transformer

Why did he pick the HV to be the side where he applied the voltage? Usually open circuit test voltage is applied at the LV side. So, from the question how can I know which side he performed the open circuit test on?
[image]

SOURCE:

Basic Electrical and Electronics Engineering-I

Fifth Edition, 2015

Abhijit Chakrabarti

Sudipta Debnath

McGraw Hill Education (India) Private Limited

ISBN (13): 978-93-392-2204-8

ISBN (10): 93-392-2204-0

Comment: If you're testing a transformer, energising the HV winding means that all the other windings will have lower, safer, voltages on them.

Comment: *Usually open circuit test voltage is applied at the LV side* - that is not true. It is applied to the primary winding.

Comment: @Andyaka, In fact, it is more common to perform the no-load test using the lower voltage winding. It is easier to obtain accuracy with the CTs by measuring the current in the lower voltage winding (the current is higher).